# Windows XP embedded prevent cookie wipe for specific Site

Tags: internet-explorer-7, windows-xp-embedded

I have a kiosk that is setup on a XPe machine. Currently it is pointed to an intranet website setup for simple registration. We have a requirement to allow vendors to access their Reptrax account using the same computer.

I have attempted several ways to make this work. What I need to know is how to protect the sites configuration information on reboot.

I have turned off the file writeprotect. Setup the website as needed and verified that on a reboot with the writeprotect off the settings are kept. once I turn the writeprotect back on the site loses its settings. I am sure that this is a cookies related issue. I have contacted Reptrax about this, but figured I would ask here as well.

as an added complication, we have ie7 in kiosk mode.

Comment: 1)  Modify the user's ability to wipe cookies.  2) Use IE8 so you get away from using an insecure browser.